# What's wrong with the break in for loop in R?

Tags: r, openxlsx

I have a code:

```
nc=10
for(n in 1:n){
  mergeCells(wb, 1, cols = (4*n):(4*n+3), rows = 1:1)
  if ((4*n)>nc) {break
  }
}
```

However it produces an error:

```
  Merge intersects with existing merged cells: 
        L1:Q1.
Remove existing merge first.
```

I do have some merged cells in L1:Q1. However the error shouldn't have occured since I specified the loop to break once 4*n > nc (where nc=10). When n=3, 4*n> nc and the loop should break. The 10th cell is J1, not L1, so the merged cells shouldn't overlap.

Comment: `for(n in 1:n)` probably not a good idea.

Comment: How should I rewrite the code?

Comment: how many loops do you want?  for e.g. 5 loops then `for(n in 1:5)`.  To run until a test is met, try using `while()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the third iteration of the loop, the code tries to merge L1:O1: (`n <- 3; LETTERS[(4*n):(4*n+3)]`), and this occurs before the break line. Swapping the order of the lines in the loop should fix it:

```
nc=10
for(n in 1:n){    ##should this be for(n in n:nc)
  if ((4*n)>nc) {break}
  mergeCells(wb, 1, cols = (4*n):(4*n+3), rows = 1:1)
}
```

Obviously without the dataset `wb` it isn't possible to check.